# DAX summarize with measures for This YR Last YR

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I am using DAX `SUMMARIZE()` as shown in [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=178rH2c3D0Y). It works great to summarize measurement for a Dimension table with relationship to Fact table. But when I try to introduce a filtered measure for "This Year" and "Last Year" columns, the calculation ignores the summarized columns and calculates the entire year.

How can I write the query to add "This Year" and "Last Year" columns that respect the summarized values.

**DAX query (#1) >**

```
Disposal Attributes (calc field) = 
VAR VolumeTotal = SUM('Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls])
VAR vol_CurrentYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) )
VAR vol_PriorYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) )

var ListTotal = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'Disposal',
    [unified_disposalId],
    [Disposal (unified_name)],
    [Disposal (groups)],
    "Volume", FORMAT(VolumeTotal, "#,#"),
    "Vol_ThisYr", FORMAT(vol_CurrentYear, "#,#"),
    "Vol_PriorYr", FORMAT(vol_PriorYear, "#,#")
)

RETURN
FILTER( 
        ListTotal, VolumeTotal > 0
    )
```

**DAX query (#2) >**

```
Disposal Attributes (calc field) = 
VAR VolumeTotal = SUM('Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls])
VAR vol_CurrentYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) )
VAR vol_PriorYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) )

var ListTotal = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'Disposal',
    [unified_disposalId],
    [Disposal (unified_name)],
    [Disposal (groups)],
    "Volume", FORMAT(VolumeTotal, "#,#")
)

RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER( 
        ListTotal, VolumeTotal > 0
    ),
    "Vol_ThisYr", FORMAT(vol_CurrentYear, "#,#"),
    "Vol_PriorYr", FORMAT(vol_PriorYear, "#,#")
)
```

**Relationships >**

[image]

**Result >**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample .pbix?

Comment: A piece of golden advice : Never use summarize() to add columns. Instead You must use ADDCOLUMNS and SUMMARIZE duo to achieve your goal. Summarize is perfect when you decide to group by columns coming from different tables in your data model.

Answer (score 1):

with "VAR vol_CurrentYear" you always get the same value. To put calculations into the row context use CALCULATE() in the ADDCOLUMNS(). You can create measures instead of variables and use them then in ADDCOLUMNS it will have the same effect.

```
Disposal Attributes (calc field) = 
VAR VolumeTotal = SUM('Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls])
--VAR vol_CurrentYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) )
--VAR vol_PriorYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) )

var ListTotal = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'Disposal',
    [unified_disposalId],
    [Disposal (unified_name)],
    [Disposal (groups)],
    "Volume", FORMAT(VolumeTotal, "#,#")
)

RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER( 
        ListTotal, VolumeTotal > 0
    ),
    "Vol_ThisYr", FORMAT(CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) ), "#,#"),
    "Vol_PriorYr", FORMAT(CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) ), "#,#")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from `Mik` got me down the correct path.

> To put calculations into the row context use CALCULATE() in the ADDCOLUMNS(). You can create measures instead of variables and use them then in ADDCOLUMNS it will have the same effect.

I noticed that the "variables" weren't working at all. Best as I can tell in PBI Desktop the `DEFINE` syntax is invalid, so I couldn't define measures, I had to add the measure definition within the query.

```
Disposal Attributes (calc field) = 
// VAR VolumeTotal = SUM( 'Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls] )
// VAR vol_CurrentYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) )
// VAR vol_PriorYear = CALCULATE(VolumeTotal, FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) )

var ListTotal = 
SUMMARIZE (
    'Disposal',
    [unified_disposalId],
    [Disposal (unified_name)],
    [Disposal (groups)],
    "Volume", SUM( 'Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls] )
)

RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER( 
        ListTotal, [Volume] > 0
    ),
    "Vol_ThisYr", FORMAT(CALCULATE(SUM( 'Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls] ), FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())) ), "#,#"),
    "Vol_PriorYr", FORMAT(CALCULATE(SUM( 'Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls] ), FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())-1) ), "#,#"),
    "Volume (,)", FORMAT( [Volume], "#,#")
)
```

Result >

[image]

Comment: The one who puts calculations into row context is not calculate function. It is ADDCOLUMNS function which is an iterator that creates a row context automatically wherever It is used. The task of calculate here is to convert the existing row context into equivalent filter context. we call this 'context transition'.

Comment: if you create a single measure `VolumeTotal = SUM('Piped Trucked Volume'[volume_bbls])`, Then you can use it in your `Disposal Attributes (calc field)` measure like  `..."Vol_ThisYr", FORMAT(CALCULATE([VolumeTotal], FILTER(...` So the code overall will be shorter. the only thing you should always have in mind it will be covered by DAX with CALCULATE()  as follows `CALCULATE([VolumeTotal])`